# Get the dictionary element number in swift

Tags: swift

I have a [string:bool] dictionary as follows

```
["name1":true,"name2":false,"name3":true]
```

I want to take the index numbers of the keys with true boolean values

```
    for(product,value) in products{
        if(value == true){
             print()       
     }
   }
```

how can I do this

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. Practically they don't have fixed indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a more elegant, 'Swifty' solution to your problem. ForEach is a functional addition to the Swift language.

```
let dict = ["name1": true, "name2": false, "name3": true]
dict.forEach { (product, value) in
  if value == true { dict.index(forKey: key) }
}
```

Although, you can also `filter` on the `dict`, to have a new dictionary with *only* the records where the value is true.

```
let trueDict = dict.filter { return $1 }
```

Comment: Are you sure that dict.forEach command gives the exact same indices always? That might cause problems because of dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: While I am aware of that, I think my answer does the thing the TS is asking for. I also suggest a `filter` instead of looping, so I think TS should be fine. However, it **is** a concern that dictionaries are unordered and there might be unexpected results.